# == operator cannot be applied of type int and string -- LINQ statement with ==

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am writing a LINQ statement like this

```
var v1 = from c in context.Orders
         join c1 in context.Order_Details
         on c.OrderID equals c1.OrderID
         where c.CustomerID == 1
         group c1 by c1.ProductID into x
         select x;
```

But its giving me error that

> == cannot be applied to operands of type int and string

There is following question [Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230551/comparison-operators-not-supported-for-type-system-linq-iqueryable1system-int)
But this question does not solve my problem

How can I fix the above problem, thanks

Comment: What's the type of c.CustomerID?

Comment: This is a compiler error that has nothing to do with LINQ. It is your responsibility to try to get rid of irrelevant details, before asking a question. This is the "minimal" part of [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is a compiler error that won't be reproducible without seeing your `Order` (presumably) class: that's the "complete" and "verifiable" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I take it that c.CustomerID is a string (as is common with ID properties), and that's the problem. As is pointed out above, this isn't a Linq problem.

That being said, to solve it, just replace

```
where c.CustomerID == 1
```

with

```
where c.CustomerID == "1"
```

If you have an int variable and not a constant, you can just call ToString() on it:

```
where c.CustomerID == myInt.ToString()
```

This won't work for doubles and floats though, so watch out!

Answer (score 1):

The message is self explaining, it clearly says that *"cannot be applied to operands of type int and string"*. Now look into the condition `where c.CustomerID == 1`  here `1` is integer and `c.CustomerID` is string so better you do like the following:

```
where c.CustomerID == "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is type safe language, you can't compare an `int` with a `string`. In your case it is safer to convert the integer value to its String representation:

```
where c.CustomerID == "1"
```

You can always replace that with `.ToString()` method call.

I also highly suggest you to review your model, if `CustomerID` is and integer it is better to be mapped and stored as an `integer` and not a `string`.

Comment: Cool... ! happy codding