# Linq query results in Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, contains

I have the following function:

```
public List<DTO.ArticleDTO> GetRecentArticles(int portalID, int moduleID, int domainID, int rootKnowledgeTypeID, int count)
{
    var articles =
        (from
            article in _Context.Articles.LatestArticles(_Context.ArticleVersions, portalID, moduleID)
            where _GetRootDomainsForArticle(article.ArticleID, article.Version, rootKnowledgeTypeID).Contains(domainID)
        orderby article.UpdatedOn descending
            select new ArticleDTO
            {
                ArticleID = article.ArticleID,
                Title = article.Title,
                Summary = article.Introduction,
                Content = article.Content,
                UpdatedOn = article.UpdatedOn,
                Version = article.Version,
                KnowledgeTypeText = (from
                                        category in _Context.Categories
                                    join
                                        categoryVersion in _Context.ArticleCategoryVersions
                                    on
                                        category.CategoryID equals categoryVersion.CategoryID
                                    where
                                        categoryVersion.Version == article.Version &&
                                        categoryVersion.ArticleID == article.ArticleID &&
                                        category.ParentID == rootKnowledgeTypeID
                                    select
                                        category.Name
                                ).First()
            });

    return articles.Take(count).ToList();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get all the articles that belong to a root category (domain ID). Categories are considered to be Domains/SubDomains and each article can belong to one or more Domains and Sub Domains. So this is why I used the following method in the where clause of the above linq query.

```
private IQueryable<int> _GetRootDomainsForArticle(int articleID, int version, int rootKnowledgeTypeID)
{
    return from c in _Context.Categories
                    join cv in _Context.ArticleCategoryVersions on c.CategoryID equals cv.CategoryID
                    where cv.ArticleID == articleID
                    where cv.Version == version
                    where c.ParentID == null
                    where c.CategoryID != rootKnowledgeTypeID
                    select c.CategoryID;
}
```

The error I get is: "Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]'."

I think is is because of deferred execution, but I don't quite understand the right way to do it.

**Edit:**

Based on @SivaGopal comment I moved the query from the _GetRootDomainsForArticle to become part of the main query and it worked:

```
public List<DTO.ArticleDTO> GetRecentArticles(int portalID, int moduleID, int domainID, int rootKnowledgeTypeID, int count)
{
    var articles =
        (from
            article in _Context.Articles.LatestArticles(_Context.ArticleVersions, portalID, moduleID)
            where (from c in _Context.Categories
                join cv in _Context.ArticleCategoryVersions on c.CategoryID equals cv.CategoryID
                where cv.ArticleID == article.ArticleID
                where cv.Version == article.Version
                where c.ParentID == null
                where c.CategoryID != rootKnowledgeTypeID
                select c.CategoryID).Contains(domainID)
            orderby article.UpdatedOn descending
            select new ArticleDTO
            {
                ArticleID = article.ArticleID,
                Title = article.Title,
                Summary = article.Introduction,
                Content = article.Content,
                UpdatedOn = article.UpdatedOn,
                Version = article.Version,
                KnowledgeTypeText = (from
                                category in _Context.Categories
                                    join
                                categoryVersion in _Context.ArticleCategoryVersions
                            on
                                category.CategoryID equals categoryVersion.CategoryID
                                    where
                                categoryVersion.Version == article.Version &&
                                categoryVersion.ArticleID == article.ArticleID &&
                                category.ParentID == rootKnowledgeTypeID
                                    select
                                category.Name
                        ).First()
            });

    return articles.Take(count).ToList();
}
```

My limited understanding of Linq lead me to believe that one could split that query out to a method as form of query composition and in so doing making it reusable. Seems not to be the case, but surely there must be a way to do this as it would drastically reduce code especially where portions of queries are reused quite often.

Comment: Did you try in-lining the `GetRootDomainsForArticle` query into your main query. Also [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230551/comparison-operators-not-supported-for-type-system-linq-iqueryable1system-int) may help you.

Comment: @SivaGopal that actually worked! The question is why? The data coming from the GetRootDomainsForArticle method is something I'd like to reuse for other methods so I'd really like to understand why it won't work.

Comment: My understanding is due to delayed execution, your database is unaware of what function are you trying to call, isn't it?

Comment: @SivaGopal I'm still relatively new to Linq, so still getting to grips with it, but I thought that _GetRootDomainsForArticle is returning IQueryable so I understood it to be a form of query composition.

Comment: [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970100/calling-a-method-inside-a-linq-query) could provide you more insight of what I was saying.

Comment: Unfortunately though I couldn't get much time now to try & test but [`CompiledQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.compiledquery.aspx) or `Expression<>` are the ways you can give a try as explained in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952602/how-to-reuse-where-clauses-in-linq-to-sql-queries).

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting up your function more, the long and deep Linq method can work, but it is not that good for readability purposes and can introduce these sort of bugs that you are talking about. I haven't tested this yet but it should help solve your issue:

```
public List<DTO.ArticleDTO> GetRecentArticles(int portalID, int moduleID, int domainID, int rootKnowledgeTypeID, int count)
{
    var allArticles = _Context.Articles.LatestArticles(_Context.ArticleVersions, portalID, moduleID);
    var filteredArticles = new List<DTO.ArticleDTO>();

    foreach (DTO.ArticleDTO article in allArticles)
    {
        var domains = _GetRootDomainsForArticle(article.ArticleID, article.Version, rootKnowledgeTypeID);
        if (domains.Contains(domainID)
        {
            filteredArticles.Add(article);
        }
    }

    var articles = filteredArticles.OrderBy(article.UpdatedOn).Descending().Select(article => new DTO.ArticleDTO {
        ArticleID = article.ArticleID,
        Title = article.Title,
        Summary = article.Introduction,
        Content = article.Content,
        UpdatedOn = article.UpdatedOn,
        Version = article.Version,
        KnowledgeTypeText = (from category in _Context.Categories
                                          join categoryVersion in _Context.ArticleCategoryVersions
                                          on category.CategoryID equals categoryVersion.CategoryID
                                          where
                                            categoryVersion.Version == article.Version &&
                                            categoryVersion.ArticleID == article.ArticleID &&
                                            category.ParentID == rootKnowledgeTypeID
                                          select
                                            category.Name
                                        ).First()
    }).Take(count).ToList();
}
```

Also do you absolutely need to return IQueryable<> from your _GetRootDomainsForArticle function? If you can get away with it, I'd try returning IEnumerable<> instead.

Koda

Comment: Aren't you extracting the entire list from the database like this first and then filtering? This could potentially be thousands of articles which you then need to move across the wire before filtering them?

Comment: The point is to diagnose the problem, whilst your logic is wrapped up in a multi-level linq query it is always going to be more difficult to solve problems like you are facing. Make code that works first, then optimize like you are doing so you don't use more resources than needed.

Comment: completely understand your point, I have that query running elsewhere without the where clause calling the _GetRootDomainsForArticle and it works. _GetRootDomainsFOrArticle run by itself works and is used elsewhere as well in a somewhat similar fashion to what you're suggesting but where I'm only extracting a handful of articles so the traffic across the wire isn't too much of a concern